# How to Customize Rainbow-Delimiter and Emacs-Color for a theme with Dark Background

Tags: init-file, colors

I have installed rainbow-delimiter packages, and I tried to customize it based
on the code written in [this page](https://github.com/mariusk/emacs-color).
However, I found out that some generated colors are too dark when it is used 
with a theme with a dark background such as Zenburn.

My question is how to customize it so that the generated color can be more brighter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you really want random colors from the code, try giving a higher value for the l parameter, which obviously stands for the lightness in the HSL representation. Maybe also reducing the saturation (s) helps. I.e. something like

```
((... (set-random-rainbow-colors 0.3 0.8))) ;; instead of 0.5 0.49
```

---

*If* you just want to have custom colors for `rainbow-delimiters-mode`, customize the group "Rainbow delimiters faces", by

```
M-x customize-group <ret> rainbow-delimiters-faces
```

(I would actually prefer the colors *not* to be random, so one immedeately sees "I am on the outer level now" and such.)

Comment: Thanks @pingi, To add more information here in addition to his answer, since I use the zenburn theme I found that I like this setting most 0.8 0.6 0.7. Thus, in my init file, I write ... '(lambda () (set-random-rainbow-colors 0.8 0.6 0.7)))